# How to copy a part of an ArrayList, change and add to the same ArrayList?

Tags: java, javafx, arraylist

I will create an `ArrayList` to which I will add 5 elements.

```
// This is just an example
var rectangles = new ArrayList<>(20) {
    {
        add(new Rectangle(10, 10, Color.RED));
        add(new Rectangle(20, 20, Color.GREEN));
        add(new Rectangle(30, 30, Color.YELLOW));
        add(new Rectangle(40, 40, Color.BLUE));
        add(new Rectangle(50, 50, Color.PURPLE));
    }
};
```

The remaining 15 elements don't need to be written, because the first five will only be repeated, but each five will have a specific property set.

It is better to see it on the code.

```
for (var angle = 90; angle <= 270; angle += 90) {
    var part_of_array = rectangles.subList(0, 5);
    var rotate = new Rotate(angle, 500, 500);
    part_of_array.stream().forEach(t -> ((Rectangle) t).getTransforms().add(rotate));  
    rectangles.addAll(part_of_array);
}
```

But the code is complicated and, most importantly, doesn't work at all. As a result, the array has 20 elements, but they all have an **angle** set to **90**.

How to write it correctly, please?

Thank you

Comment: What does getTransforms() and add() do? May be share the rectangle class

Comment: Sorry, this is a [JavaFX class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Rectangle.html) 
add() is adding an element to the arraylist and [getTransforms()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getTransforms--) returns ObservableList <Transform> where you can add various transformations of the object - translate, scale and rotate.

Comment: You are very likely to be shallow copying the references to the same objects

Comment: Yes, the problem is that all the elements are always adjusted. Although I don't understand why the angle is 90 and not 270. That's why I wanted to know how to copy it to avoid it. I know there are different ways to copy, but I've never used it.

Comment: You’re just repeatedly setting the `rotate`property of the same rectangles on each iteration of the loop, so they will just have the last value set. If you want elements in the list with different rotate values,  you can’t reuse the same objects, you need to create new `Rectangle`s.

Comment: [mcve] please and stick to java naming conventions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Streams for that job:

Option 1:

```
List<Rectangle> rectangles = Stream.of(new Rectangle(10, 10, Color.RED),
                                        new Rectangle(20, 20, Color.GREEN),
                                        new Rectangle(30, 30, Color.YELLOW),
                                        new Rectangle(40, 40, Color.BLUE),
                                        new Rectangle(50, 50, Color.PURPLE))
    .flatMap(rectangle -> 
            IntStream.range(0, 4).mapToObj(i -> {
                var newRectangle = new Rectangle(rectangle.getWidth(), rectangle.getHeight(), rectangle.getFill());
                newRectangle.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(90 * i, 500, 500));
                return newRectangle;
            }))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Option 2:

Given that your rectangles are squares (height == width), you can also do:

```
Map<Integer, Color> map = Map.of(10, Color.RED, 20, Color.GREEN, 30, Color.YELLOW, 40, Color.BLUE, 50, Color.PURPLE);

List<Rectangle> rectangles = map.entrySet().stream()
    .flatMap(entry -> IntStream.range(0, 4).mapToObj(i -> {
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(entry.getKey(), entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            rectangle.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(90 * i, 500, 500));
            return rectangle;
        }))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Update**

Option 1:

To maintain the order you need to use Comparator and invert the streams.

```
List<Rectangle> rectangles = IntStream.range(0, 4).boxed()
    .flatMap(i -> 
        Stream.of(new Rectangle(10, 10, Color.RED),
                    new Rectangle(20, 20, Color.GREEN),
                    new Rectangle(30, 30, Color.YELLOW),
                    new Rectangle(40, 40, Color.BLUE),
                    new Rectangle(50, 50, Color.PURPLE))
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Rectangle::getWidth))
        .map(rectangle -> {
            var newRectangle = new Rectangle(rectangle.getWidth(), rectangle.getHeight(), rectangle.getFill());
            newRectangle.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(90 * i, 500, 500));
            return newRectangle;
        }))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Option 2:

To maintain the order you need to use a TreeMap and invert the streams.

```
Map<Integer, Color> map = Map.of(10, Color.RED, 20, Color.GREEN, 30, Color.YELLOW, 40, Color.BLUE, 50, Color.PURPLE);

Map<Integer, Color> treeMap = new TreeMap<>(map);

List<Rectangle> rectangles = IntStream.range(0, 4).boxed()
    .flatMap(i -> 
        treeMap.entrySet().stream().map(entry -> {
                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(entry.getKey(), entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                rectangle.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(90 * i, 500, 500));
                return rectangle;
        }))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank you. Like I said, this is just an example. Unfortunately, the elements aren't in the correct order. I wanted the elements to be repeated, but in the current order - **1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5**. However, your code will create - **1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5**. Is there any way to adjust it for such a result, please? Thank you

Comment: yoda666, sure. For that you need a TreeMap and invert the streams. I updated the answer to include this.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. It's right now. Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry, but one more question. How would you edit the first code - Stream.of... so that the sorting was correct too?  Thank you

Comment: yoda666, I updated the answer to include both alternatives.

Comment: Yes. That is all. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new list from the sublist to avoid altering the initial list and you need to clone each rectangle:

```
var part_of_array = new ArrayList<Rectangle>(rectangles.subList(0, 5));
var rotate = new Rotate(angle, 500, 500);
part_of_array.stream().forEach(t -> ((Rectangle) t.clone()).getTransforms().add(rotate));  
rectangles.addAll(part_of_array);
```

Comment: My mistake. Deleted my comments as they were of no help.